minimalmodbus ErrorSlave reported illegal function
I'm having problem with minimalmodbus library. The slave does not recognise the functioncode and shows ErrorSlave reported illegal function, I want to request a read on an input register. I'm using the Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. I'm using the Geolux RSS-2-300WL Flow Rate Sensor as a slave.
What i did is mention the functioncode=4.
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Import all library needed
import minimalmodbus
import serial
import time
import logging

# Configuration of the sensor
geolux = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttySC0', 1) #(port number, slave ID)
geolux.serial.baudrate = 9600
geolux.serial.bytesize = 8
geolux.serial.parity = serial.PARITY_EVEN
geolux.serial.stopbits = 1
geolux.serial.timeout = 1 

# Main Loop
try:
    while True:
        try:
            # Read raw reading for water level
            water_level_raw = geolux.read_register(0x0012,2,functioncode=4) #(address register, byte read) 
            print(f"Raw water level: {water_level_raw}")

The error is:

The data sheet from the device manual is:


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your error as text and not as an image.  Incidentally, aren't you missing some sort of except: part of your try: block?

Would recommend using a known good app (e.g. mbpoll/modpoll) to test before writing a program. Your code looks OK, but the data is stored over two registers and, sometimes, devices return unexpected errors when you request one register when it's expected you would read 2 (so try requesting two registers - e.g. read_float(0x12,3,2)).

@ewokx thanks for clarifying. I purposedly paste only half of the code as the other half is not done yet. But thank you! I am still figuring out the way here. this is the rest of the code.

@Brits Thank you, will try out the apps mentioned. The minimalmodbus library does have a function to read float and also long character.     read_long(registeraddress: int, functioncode: int = 3, signed: bool = False, byteorder: int = 0, number_of_registers: int = 2) → int     but the function code seems fix which cannot be change for the slave to read.

@user28387204 the spec indicates that the field is a 32-bit float, so read_float would be the appropriate function (but I did not check Endianness so that part may be wrong). Confused by your comment "function code seems fix", the function definition is very similar to read_register.

@Brits I think the questioner is misunderstanding the default keyword argument functioncode: int = 3, thinking that is fixing/locking the function code to 3. @user28387204 geolux.read_float(0x12, 4) should be what you're after. To check endianness, use the test register, geolux.read_float(0x6, 4) should return -123.4567. Please [update] your question to include anything you've tried and errors that you've encountered.
